# suggestion about implement sms app in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, express

Im using third parties sms service provider it cost more to my services so im interested create my own sms gateway app in MEAN stack technologies. i was searched lot of things but could not get proper information about implementation SMS app  so anyone suggest to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) for this. You send them the message and the number via a REST API call and you get notified of its status by webhooks.

Comment: I want to develop my own app like Twilio

Comment: It will require some work. One solution would be a Raspberry Pi with a SIM module. You just need a SIM card with an active telecom subscription.

Comment: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-cellular , https://www.roundsolutions.com/en/raspberry-pi-cellular-adapter/